# Nearest Neighbor using customized weights on Python scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

Good night,

I would like to use Nearest Neighbor model for Regression with non-uniform weights. I saw in the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) that I can use `weights='distance'` in the declaration of the model and then the weights would be inverse proportional to the distance, but the results I get were not what I wanted.

I saw in the [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor) that I could use a function for the weights (given the distances) used in the prediction, so I have created the follow function:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
import numpy
nparray = numpy.array

def customized_weights(distances: nparray)->nparray:
    for distance in distances:
        if (distance >= 100 or distance <= -100):
            yield  0

        yield (1 - abs(distance)/100)
```

And have declared the method like this:

```
knn: KNeighborsRegressor = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=50, weights=customized_weights ).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Until that part, everything works fine. But when I tried to predict with the model, I get the error:

```
  File "knn_with_weights.py", line 14, in customized_weights
    if (distance >= 100 or distance <= -100):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I did not understand what I did wrong. On the [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor) it is written that my function should has an array of distances as parameter and should return the equivalent weights. What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [@Jeff H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10789207/jeff-h)'s tip directed me to the answer.

The input parameter of this function is a two dimensional numpy array `distances` with shape `(predictions, neighbors)`, where:

- predictions is the number of desired predictions (when you call `knn.predict(X_1, X_2, X_3, ...)`;
- neighbors, the number of neighbors used (in my case, n_neighbors=50).

Each element `distances[i, j]` represents the distance for the `i` prediction, from the `j` nearest neighbor (the smaller `j`, smaller the distance).

The function must return an array with the same dimensions as the input array, with the weight corresponding to each distance.

I do not know if it is the fastest way, but I came up with this solution:

```
def customized_weights(distances: nparray)->nparray:

    weights: nparray = nparray(numpy.full(distances.shape, 0), dtype='float')
# create a new array 'weights' with the same dimension of  'distances' and fill 
# the array with 0 element.
    for i in range(distances.shape[0]): # for each prediction:
        if distances[i, 0] >= 100: # if the smaller distance is greather than 100, 
                                   # consider the nearest neighbor's weight as 1 
                                   # and the neighbor weights will stay zero
            weights[i, 0] = 1
                                   # than continue to the next prediction
            continue

        for j in range(distances.shape[1]): # aply the weight function for each distance

            if (distances[i, j] >= 100):
                continue

            weights[i, j] = 1 - distances[i, j]/100

    return weights
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this type of regression, but it is certainly possible that the distances passed into this is a 2-dimensional data structure, which would make sense for all pairwise-distances.

Why don't you put a little teaser print statement into your custom function to print both `distances` and `distances.shape`